# How can I push a page from one MediaWiki to another SSL based wiki with self signed certificate using the Push extension?

Tags: ssl-certificate, mediawiki

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Push
is an extension that will let you push pages from one MediaWiki toanother.

As documented in
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Saza08eh1dcygs3c
I had trouble getting this to work with target Mediawikis that use SSL and self signed certificates.

Push would choke up with the message: Dateitransfer fehlgeschlagen: Authentifizierung auf https:///api.php ist fehlgeschlagen.

The issue is now solved and I am adding this question to make the solution available for Stackoverflow users to find.

Answer (score 0):

First as outlined in https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Saza08eh1dcygs3c

https://github.com/BITPlan/Push/commit/cf393a32423bd8ae07af50a5587f847f20cfb9b9

has a commit with a few extra lines for error handling. The resulting message is:

Authentication at .../mediawiki/api.php(http-curl-error:SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate) failed.

This is a major improvement in handling such situations - especially the debugging works better.

So the natural attempt to add:

1. ini_set("openssl.cafile","BITPlanValidCerts.pem")
2. ini-set("curl.cainfo","BITPlanValidCerts.pem")

didn't work - you have to set these in the php.ini file. A curl https:// test then works. But still no go with Mediawiki and the push extension.

https://github.com/BITPlan/Push/commit/3f68dd36a65ff6ad8c68df807c2c32311073dae4

fixes the issue by adding the curl.cainfo php ini setting to the curl options

```
getHttpRequest( $target,
            array(
            array(
                'postData' => $requestData,
                'postData' => $requestData,
                'method' => 'POST',
                'method' => 'POST',
-               'timeout' => 'default'
+               'timeout' => 'default',
+               'caInfo' => ini_get('curl.cainfo')
            )
            )
        );
        );
```

The same fix might also apply to similar situations where the upgrade advice:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Extension_support/1.17/ExtUpgrading

has been followed. MWHttpRequest will handle the caInfo option if it is supplied see https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/HttpFunctions_8php_source.html